# How to translate token names in bison

Tags: internationalization, bison

I have a bison parser that works sufficiently well for my purpose. It even prints localized error messages. But the token names are not translated. Looking at the source code I found, that I can use define `YY_` to my own gettext function and pass `YY_` to gettext in order to provide my own translation of the error messages. But this does not work for token names.

Is there some switch or hidden feature that I could use to extract the token names from the parser and to translate them?

So far I found `yytnamerr` which could be overridden to format the token names. As it does more than just reformat names I don't like to touch this function, as I would have to sync it with the progress of Bison. On the other hand, I need also a way to extract the token names from the parser in order to add them to the language definition file.

How do you implement user friendly error reporting with Bison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specify `%token-table`, then bison will generate the `yytname` table. This table includes all bison symbols, including internal symbols (`$end`, `$error` and `$undefined`), terminals -- named, single-quoted characters and double-quoted strings -- and non-terminals, which include also the generated names for mid-rule actions.

With `yytname` visible, it's easy to extract the tokens in a format recognizable by the `gettext` package. For example, you could add to your `.y` file something like this:

```
#ifdef MAKE_TOKEN
int main(void) {
   puts("#include <libintl.h>");
   puts("#include <stdio.h>");
   puts("int main() {");
   for (const char* const* p = yytname; *p; ++p) {
     // See Note 1 below
     printf("  printf(\"%%s: %%s\\n\", \"%s\", gettext (\"%s\"));\n", *p, *p);
   }
   puts("}");
 }
 #endif
```

and then add a stanza to your Makefile (making appropriate substitutions for file names):

```
messages.pot: my_parser.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DMAKE_TOKEN -o token_lister $<
    ./token_lister > my_parser.tokens.c
    # See Note 2 below
    $(CC) -o my_parser.tokens my_parser.tokens.c
    xgettext -o $@ my_parser.tokens.c
```

Once you have the translations, you still need to figure out how to use them, since bison does not offer an interface for inserting translated token names into its generated error messages. Probably the simplest way is to insert the translations directly into `yytname` by iterating through that array and substituting each token name with its translation (that would have to be done at parser startup). That presents the annoyance that `yytname` is declared `const` by the bison skeleton; however, a very simple `sed` or `awk` invocation can be used to remove the offending `const`. [Note 3]

Having said that, it's not at all clear to me that these automatically generated error messages are "user friendly", unless the user is surprisingly familiar with the language's formal grammar. And a user who is familiar with the grammar might well prefer the original token name, in order to find it in the grammar, rather than a non-expert translation which only coincidentally resembles the original concept. Not that I'm pointing fingers at anyone in particular.

You might enjoy this [fascinating essay](http://research.swtch.com/yyerror) by Russ Cox, about how he implemented actually friendly error messages for Go.

---

**NOTES**:

1. The direct use of the token name in a C string won't work in the case of the tokens whose representation includes a `"` or a `\`. In particular, any keyword token (`"and"` or `"<="`) will fail, as will the single character tokens `'"'` and `'\\'`. These don't show up very often in grammars; if you're substituting internationalized keywords in your scanner, you're very unlikely to use bison's quoted string feature at all.

   If you do want to use such tokens, you'll have to output code for the gettext generator which escapes `"` and `\` characters in the token name.
2. Actually, it would be better to use several stanzas, but that one is enough to get you going, I think. You probably want to mark some or all of the intermediate results as `.INTERMEDIATE`. The generated executable `my_parser.tokens` can be used to verify the translations, but that's totally optional, so you might want to remove that line. On the other hand, it does verify that the strings are compilable.
3. See Russ Cox's `gc` (link provided above) for an example. His Makefile modifies the bison output to remove the `const` from `yytname`, so that the generated parser can substitute his preferred token names for error messages, so you can see the general idea at work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately `%token-table` is not enough as I can not extract the strings for translation automatically. I have already human readable grammar descriptions for different human languages using different human-readable token names. And I want to output the error messages using these human-readable token names. Additionally each reserved word exists in at least two flavours: English and German. So far this is managed by the scanner. So I can't unconditionally use the keywords of only one language.

Comment: @keinstein: you won't find keywords in yytname if they are only present in the scanner, and as far as I can see the only purpose of yytnamerr is to make the names in yytname presentable to the end-user, so translating them would be just fine (although of course you do have to preserve, and therefore track, the API.)

Comment: The keywords are presentable except the problem that they are not translated so far. There is another problem: gettext doesn't know about the keywords in `yytname`. So it can't extract them. How do I get them automatically extractble?

Comment: @Keinstein: OK, answer edited. As you probably know, conventional wisdom about translation (and the gettext manual) discourage interpolating individually translated words into translated messages, because it doesn't work with all languages. But it's probably fine for the languages you care about.

Comment: Usually I make very few assumptions about the translations. In that point I agree with you. But it would be a wrong to ignore the error messages generated by bison as they provide cases that aren't catched elsewhere as I neither invented the language nor wrote the grammar file. I have not the time to rework the bison grammar (it's necessary but other problems have higher priority). So language consistent error messages are a huge improvement. Even if the translations must circumvent the human grammar. Your answer is acceptable (defining `yytnamerr`). I wait some days for a different approach.